# psql not using the right index for select query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

```
Table - user
Columns:
id
name
age
account_id
deleted_at

Indexes:
"user_account_id_idx" btree (account_id)
"user_account_id_deleted_at_idx" btree (account_id, deleted_at)
```

```
Explain analyze SELECT * FROM user WHERE account_id = '00000010005009' AND deleted_at IS NULL;

Index Scan using user_account_id_idx on user (actual time=0.451..0.475 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (account_id = '00000010005009'::bpchar)
         Filter: (deleted_at IS NULL)
```

Should the query use this index - user_account_id_deleted_at_idx.
Any idea what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Why do you think the other index would be more efficient? Also: the query runs in about 0.027 **milli**seconds - how fast do you need that to be?

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table. Sometimes scanning the file is faster than using the index.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` without an `ORDER BY` makes no sense.  SQL Sets are un-ordered, you have no guarantee you'll get the same record back each time.  As for your specific question, if the stats suggest that the majority of accounts only have one record, using the shallower index can be more efficient.  Refresh the table statistics *(with `ANALYZE`)* and try again.  But, as pointed out, if it's taking 27 micro-seconds, why do you care?  Strikes me as premature optimization based on a non-representative sample size.

Comment: Yes, removed limit now.
Also, Records were less in the env where i ran explain. In actual env query was taking around 400ms

Comment: Then please **[edit]**  your question and add the (complete) execution plan from the slow environment

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, added

Comment: That's weird, you're looking for id 00000000005001 and the database is searching for id 00000010005009. Something is wrong. And this query is way faster than 400ms, more like half a microsecond. Could you please show us the complete query and complete output from this query, without editing this result?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL thinks that both indexes work equally well for this query, probably because `account_id = '00000010005009'` is already a very selective condition. All other things equal, PostgreSQL prefers to scan the smaller of the indexes.